# Why did this the SQL parser execute this illegal syntax?

Tags: sql, compiler-construction

I have a stored procedure in this form:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[fooBar]
(
)
AS
BEGIN
-- etc
RETURN  @Success
END
```

It had been working perfectly with `BEGIN` and `END` in it before, but after changing something and reverting it back, it refused to execute, pointing to a syntax error at the last `END` (removing that next pointed to a syntax error at the first IF/BEGIN/.... statement inside the procedure, and thus begins your wild goose chase).

Looking at the [MSDN official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189762.aspx) for the syntax, `BEGIN` and `END` used in this way to envelope a stored procedure is illegal.  (Removing the `BEGIN` and `END` solved the problem)

**Question: Why did this happen?**

Did the compiler skip over this `BEGIN` and `END` initially and later discover it? Are there some things that the SQL compiler ignores? Is it legacy? Is it just finicky? Am I missing a hotfix?

This is `SQL Server 10.50.1617`

Comment: BEGIN and END are not illegal to delimit procedures:  One or more Transact-SQL statements comprising the body of the procedure. You can use the optional BEGIN and END keywords to enclose the statements.    They are optional, but not illegal...

Comment: `BEGIN` and `END` are equivalent to `{` and `}` in many languages.  You could put BEGIN and END around each and every individual statement if you really wanted to.

Comment: In all likelyhood, you had other mis-matched BEGIN / END elements such that there was an internal error that was only caught when the parser got to the end of file and only then realized something was wrong.  Pretty analgous to having one too many { braces in Java/C#.

Comment: I think the problem might be the RETURN @Success line, since stored procedures aren't expected to return a value

Comment: @Sparky You are wrong. They return an integer value.

Comment: They do return an integer, but that too is optional (I THINK it defaults to zero, but not sure).   I am not sure what the compiler would do if the return type is not declared integer...

Comment: @Sparky If no return value is assigned, then under debugger you'll see a warning, Returning `null` from a stored procedure, cannot do, converted to `0` instead.

Comment: What will the compiler do if you attempt to return a varchar variable from a stored procedure? Will it compile or give an error? The user seems to be trying to determine why the compiler was reporting an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BEGIN`/`END` are perfectly valid for a stored procedure. This is explicitly set in the grammar at the documentation page you linked to.

It is the parentheses that are not allowed.